# How to remove '#' from url using $stateProvider in angularjs

Tags: angularjs

I am using $stateProvider for nesting of states.

Now my url looks likes  `localhost:8080/foo/projects#/dashboard`

the desire url is `localhost:8080/foo/projects/dashboard`

and i don't want to set html5Mode as true

```
$locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
```

with using `$stateProvider` and not setting `$locationProvider.html5Mode(true)` is there any way to achieve this url without '#'.

Please any help.
Thanks

Comment: Why don't you want to use the html5 mode?

Comment: No - you have to use html5Mode to achieve that effect